Proving the outer shape is a trapezium

I have been struggling with this problem for a number of years. It is hard to search for an answer as I don't know the name of the problem(there is a name though so if anyone can point me to this at least I'd be most grateful).
The problem can be summarised as:

Start with a triangle and extend squares from each side of the triangle
Join the corners of each square to form 3 new triangles. These have the same area as the original triangle. I am able to prove this
Extend more squares from these new triangles and connect those. I believe these form trapezia but am unable to prove it. Picture added to aid this


From this wikipedia list of various trapezium specifications, I am guessing that you intend that 2 of the sides of each trapezium are parallel.

The outer shape has 6 sides, so do you mean all 3 pairs of opposite sides are parallel? $\quad$ Note: It would be better for the figure to be an arbitrary triangle, instead of an isosceles one. $\quad$ How familiar are you with vectors? Can you set that up and solve for each vertex?

Similar to the suggestion of @Calvin Lin, if you are comfortable working in Analytical Geometry, you could specify that the vertices of the original triangle are $~(0,0), ~(1,0), ~$ and $~(x,y)~$ where $~x,y~$ are variables in $~\Bbb{R^+},~$ and see where this leads.  That is, obtain the corresponding vertices as functions of $~(x,y)~$ and then see if the corresponding line segments have the same slopes.

Also, if you intend to substitute the given diagram, that apparently starts with an isosceles triangle, with one that starts with a scalene triangle, you might also include a second diagram, that starts with an obtuse triangle.  That is, it would be interesting for you to include informal illustrations of the diagrams, where  one diagram is based on a scalene triangle, and one diagram is based on an obtuse triangle.

Given that you have established that the three surrounding triangles have equal area to the first central one (your point 2), apply the argument yet again to those surrounding triangles, which too are surrounded by squares, to generate another set of outer triangles with equal area, in the putative trapezoidal areas. But then in each outer putative trapezoid you have generated two distinct triangles on a shared base with equal area, but apices in opposite corners. Hence they lie in parallel lines. So each outer area is a trapezoid.
EDIT: Picture added. In this picture, if the white triangle generates the inner red/green/gray triangles, then each of the color triangles generates the outer colored triangles, which by transitivity are all equal in area. And the triangles are proved equal in area by, for example, $AB=AF,AC=AE, \sin{BAC}=\sin{FAE}$, so $AB \times AC \sin{BAC}=AF\times AE\sin{FAE}$.

This construct has been explored before, it has additional properties, and you can find out more in geometry texts such as The Pythagorean Proposition by Elisha Looney, who examined a right version of the construct by John Waterhouse:


Let the original triangle be $ABC$ and say $A(0, 0)$, $B(x, 0)$, $C(a,b)$, further assuming $x>0$ and $b>0$.
Next consider the 3 directly connected squares $ABED$, $BCGF$, and $ACHI$. Then one has $D(0, -x)$, $E(x, -x)$, $F(x+b, x-a)$, $G(a+b, x-a+b)$, $H(a-b, a+b)$, $I(-b, a)$.
Now consider the outer squares $DIJK$, $EFML$, and $GHON$. Then one derives $J(-x-a-b, a-b)$, $K(-x-a,-x-b)$, $L(3x+a, -x-b)$, $M(3x+a+b, x-a-b)$, $N(-x+3a+b, x-a+3b)$, $O(-x+3a-b, a+3b)$.
Therefrom indeed $AB || DE || KL$, $BC || FG || MN$, and $CA || HI || OJ$. Especially, the tetragons $DELK$, $FGNM$, and $HIJO$ are trapezia. - Nice observation!
--- rk


For those mentioning that I'd drawn the initial triangle as isosceles. I quickly knocked up this diagram in Powerpoint. I'm aware this can (and was intended to) be generalised as a scalene triangle. Thank you for all the contributions though. Vectors is a good way to go and I like th whole thing being framed in a giant right angled triangle
